# Field fixed by decomposition subgroup

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the rather standard and general setup where $R$ is any Dedekind domain, $L$ is some Galois extension of its field of fractions $K(R)$, with Galois group $G$, and $S$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Given any non trivial $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec} R$, let $\mathfrak{q}$ lie over $\mathfrak{p}$. Recall $G$ acts on the set of prime (which are of course maximal) ideals of $S$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$. Let $D$ be the stabiliser subgroup of $G$ fixing $\mathfrak{q}$. By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory $D$ may be corresponded with a fixed subfield of $L/K(R)$. My question would be if there exists an explicit description what this subfield is?

Note that it may be shown, with the former being easier than the latter, that firstly $S/\mathfrak{q}$ is a Galois extension of $R/\mathfrak{p}$ say with Galois group $H$, and further that there exists an epimorphism from $D$ to $H$.

For instance we may set $\zeta \in S/\mathfrak{q}$ such that $(R/\mathfrak{p})[\zeta]=S/\mathfrak{q}$. Then $\zeta$ satisfies some monic irreducible polynomial relation with coefficients in $R/\mathfrak{p}$, say $P$. Let $\zeta^*$ be any lifting of $\zeta$ in $S$ and once again $\zeta^*$ satisfies another monic irreducible polynomial relation $P^*$ with coefficients in $R$. For $L/K(R)$ is normal, all roots of $P^*$ are contained in $S$. So we may decompose $P^*= (X-\zeta^*)\prod_{i\in I}(X-\zeta_i^*)$ where $\zeta_i^*$ are the other roots of $P^*$. The canonical image of $P^*$ under $S[X]\rightarrow (S/\mathfrak{q})[X]$, by virtue of admitting $\zeta$ as a solution, shall be a factor of $P$. Let $J$ be a subset of $I$ such that the canonical image of $(X-\zeta^*)\prod_{j\in J} (X-\zeta_j)$ is precisely $P$. Is it true that the coefficients of $(X-\zeta^*)\prod_{j\in J} (X-\zeta_j)$ (which are not all contained in $K(R)$ should $J$ be a proper subset of $I$) are fixed by $D$?

Side note: I don't have a strong foundation in (algebraic) number theory whence I apologise for any mistake(s) or anything silly in this post.

Answer (score 1):

1. Another description of the fixed field $F$ of $D$, called the decomposition field of $\frak q$ over $\frak p$, is the following: It is the largest intermediate field $E$ of $L/K(R)$ with the property that both $e({\frak q}\cap E\mid {\frak p})$ and $f({\frak q}\cap E\mid {\frak p})$ equal $1$.
   If $G$ is abelian we can further improve this to: $F$ is the largest intermediate field in which $\frak p$ splits completely.
2. Just a nitpick but: $S/\frak q$ is not necessarily Galois over $R/\frak p$ as this extension might not be separable.
3. The reduction of $P^*$ mod $\frak q$ has $\zeta$ as a root and coefficients in $R/\frak p$, so it is a **multiple** of $P$.